# Mouse Wheel scroll to sections using section tags. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

Im trying to use the jquery-mousewheel plugin to scroll to sections. My problem is that each section is contained inside a section tag. Is it possible to use the scroll effect on those containers somehow?

My HTML:

```
<div class="inner-page-wrap has-no-sidebar clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="page-content hfeed clearfix">
            <div class="clearfix post-14 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="14">
                <section id="section-1" data-rowname="" class="row fw-row">
                    <div class="spb-row-container spb-row-full-width spb_parallax_asset sf-parallax parallax-window-height col-sm-12 section-1  col-window-height slided" data-v-center="false" data-top-style="none" data-bottom-style="none">
                    </div> 
                </section>
                <section id="section-2" data-rowname="" class="row fw-row">
                    <div class="spb-row-container spb-row-full-width spb_parallax_asset sf-parallax parallax-window-height col-sm-12 section-2  col-window-height" data-v-center="false" data-top-style="none" data-bottom-style="none">
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section id="section-3" data-rowname="" class="row fw-row">
                    <div class="spb-row-container spb-row-full-width spb_parallax_asset sf-parallax parallax-window-height col-sm-12 section-3  col-window-height" data-v-center="false" data-top-style="none" data-bottom-style="none">
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pzgpz/368/

If I remove the section-containers it works great. I've tried to change the script to use the section selectors, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It is pretty stupid but it works perfectly. Checkout the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzgpz/369/). I only did one thing. I moved the classes from your div's (inside your sections) to your section and it works. You might want to check if all the classes are really required. I did not touch them because I do not know if you need them somewhere else in your code.

```
<div class="inner-page-wrap has-no-sidebar clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="page-content hfeed clearfix">
            <div class="clearfix post-14 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="14">
                <section id="section-1" data-rowname="" class="row fw-row spb-row-container spb-row-full-width spb_parallax_asset sf-parallax parallax-window-height col-sm-12 section-1 col-window-height slide">
                    Part 1
                </section>
                <section id="section-2" data-rowname="" class="row fw-row spb-row-container spb-row-full-width spb_parallax_asset sf-parallax parallax-window-height col-sm-12 section-2 col-window-height">
                    Part 2
                </section>
                <section id="section-3" data-rowname="" class="row fw-row spb-row-container spb-row-full-width spb_parallax_asset sf-parallax parallax-window-height col-sm-12 section-3 col-window-height">
                    Part 3
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunaly I cant do that. Its a wordpress installation and I have to work with the current HTML. Thanks though!

Comment: @user3344734 Is it a plug-in or a template or? Because in some cases you should be able to change the classes.

Comment: The sections is created by a themebuilt visual composer. I dont want to change how it renders the HTML, so im stuck with that.